# Python - Fastesty way to find the sum of a list of coordinates

Tags: python, arrays, optimization, scikit-image

I'm optimizing a program that involves averaging all of the pixel values in a line across a black and white image.

The Line:
I'm using scimage to generate a list of coordinates, given as two ndarrays (one for X and one for Y).

The Image:
I'm using PIL to get a PixelAccess object, which acts like a 2D array of pixels.

What's the fastest way to average every pixel in the list of coordinates? Currently it's the biggest bottleneck by far. My current solution is this:

```
def sumPoints(xx,yy, refPixels):
    pointSum = 0
    for i in range(len(xx)):
        pointSum += refPixels[int(xx[i]),int(yy[i])]
    return pointSum / len(xx)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could start out with

```
pointSum = sum(RefPixels[int(x), int(y)]) for x, y in zip(xx, yy))
```

I'm not really familiar with PixelAccess.  How similar is it to Numpy arrays?  Because Numpy would let you use xx and yy to directly create a sub-array.

Comment: I'm working on converting everything to numpy arrays for that exact reason! Thanks, I'll add this in.

Comment: Unfortunately your first suggestion slows everything down significantly! Not sure why.

Comment: Huh.  That's surprising.  I was expecting a minor improvement.  I suppose if `x` and `y` are PixelAccess arrays instead of standard arrays, Python might not know how to optimize it.  How big are `x` and `y` relative to the number of pixels?  Are they picked at random?  Are they points that satisfy some criteria?